# Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\Gouvernorat" given at property path "gouvernorat"

Tags: symfony, frameworks

So I have this Drop-down in my form which I'm trying to populate from a database. I want the drop down to show the names of the governorats and insert the chosen one's name in the database.
I have this Entity called Gouvernorat:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GouvernoratRepository")
 */
class Gouvernorat
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nom;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And another called Parking:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ParkingRepository")
 */
class Parking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=55)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $gouvernorat;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) 
     */
    private $delegation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $datemise;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $statue;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nombreplaces;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TypeParking")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $type;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getDelegation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->delegation;
    }

    public function setDelegation(string $delegation): self
    {
        $this->delegation = $delegation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(string $adresse): self
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatemise(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datemise;
    }

    public function setDatemise(\DateTimeInterface $datemise): self
    {
        $this->datemise = $datemise;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatue(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->statue;
    }

    public function setStatue(bool $statue): self
    {
        $this->statue = $statue;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNombreplaces(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nombreplaces;
    }

    public function setNombreplaces(int $nombreplaces): self
    {
        $this->nombreplaces = $nombreplaces;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?TypeParking
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?TypeParking $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getGouvernorat(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gouvernorat;
    }

    public function setGouvernorat(string $gouvernorat): self
    {
        $this->gouvernorat = $gouvernorat;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And finally the form called ParkingType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Parking;
use App\Entity\TypeParking;
use App\Entity\Gouvernorat;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')


            ->add('gouvernorat', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => Gouvernorat::class,

                // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'choice_value' => 'nom',
            ])
            //->add('gouvernorat')

            ->add('delegation')
            ->add('adresse')
            ->add('datemise')
            ->add('statue', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    'Activé' => true,
                    'Desactivé' => false,
                ],
            ])
            ->add('nombreplaces')
            ->add('type',EntityType::class, [
                'class' => TypeParking::class,
                'choice_label' => 'libelle',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Parking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The drop down gets populated just fine, but whenever I try to submit the form I get the following error:

```
Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\Gouvernorat" given at property path "gouvernorat".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the form type `EntityType::class` would expect your entity field to be a `OneToOne` relationship with the class `Gouvernorat`, in your entity `Parking`, and not a `string` as you defined it.

That should be the fix you are looking for:
In `App\Entity\Parking`

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Gouvernorat;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ParkingRepository")
 */
class Parking
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Gouvernorat")
     */
    private $gouvernorat;

    // ...

    public function getGouvernorat(): ?Gouvernorat
    {
        return $this->gouvernorat;
    }

    public function setGouvernorat(Gouvernorat $gouvernorat): self
    {
        $this->gouvernorat = $gouvernorat;

        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: weird it keeps giving me "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Gouvernorat could not be converted to string"

Comment: Have you adapted your db schema with this? You should end up with a table `parking` having a FK to `gouvernorat` and in the field `gouvernorat_id` and no more `gouvernorat` field in a `VARCHAR` type

Comment: ah you're right, I added it and it worked, it inserted the id of the selected choice, I changed the relation to ManytoOne since I'm gonna use each choice more than once. Thank you

Comment: btw how can I get the value of the name field from the table gouvernorat ?

Comment: In a twig file you mean? Entities relations are lazy loaded in doctrine so considering `parking` is an instance of  `App\Entity\Parking`, you should be able to do `parking.gouvernorat.nom`, but since you now have a many relation, you should actually get a collection, so you should loop through your `gouvernorat` collection